# Issue adding multiple visualforce components to a page

Tags: css, components, visualforce

Im using a visualforce component multiple times on a page but the hover doesnt open any of the dialogs. I guess it is due to the ids but Im not sure what to do to fix.

Here is eg of the code for the visualforce component

```
<apex:attribute name="Contents" description="display message" type="string" required="true" assignto="{!DialogMessage}" />
<style>
        .modal {
          display: none; /* Hidden by default */
          position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
          z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
          padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
          left: 0;
          top: 0;
          width: 100%; /* Full width */
          height: 100%; /* Full height */
          overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
          background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
          background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
        }
        
        /* Modal Content */
        .modal-content {
          background-color: #fefefe;
          margin: auto;
          padding: 20px;
          border: 1px solid #888;
          width: 80%;
          height: 80px;
          -moz-border-radius: 15px !IMPORTANT;
          border-radius: 15px !IMPORTANT;
        }
        
        /* The Close Button */
        .close {
          color: #aaaaaa;
          float: right;
          font-size: 28px;
          font-weight: bold;
          margin-top: -20px
        }
        
        .close:hover,
        .close:focus {
          color: #000;
          text-decoration: none;
          cursor: pointer;
        }


        a.ActionObject:hover#ModalBox1 {
            display:inline;
        }
        </style>        
        <a id="ActionObject" >        
            <img src="/s.gif" />
        <div id="ModalBox1" class="modal">
            <!-- Modal content -->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <span class="close">&times;</span>
                <p><center>{!DialogMessage}</center></p>
            </div>
        
        </div>
    </a>

The part that is the issue is 
        a.ActionObject:hover#ModalBox1 {
            display:inline;
        }
```

Ive tried using javascript and have used different methods in css such as using ~ etc but none worked
If I use javascript then somehow the javascript will need to identify the correct Id to know which component to show

Answer (score 0):

Couple ideas you'll have to play with.

1. `a.ActionObject:hover#ModalBox1` won't match. You don't have anything with class "ActionObject", you have element with id (`<a id="ActionObject" >`).
2. You'll have to check generated html, you're probably victim of VF mangling your IDs into something like `j_id0:j_id1:j_id3:j_id58:ModalBox1` (generated from top, ID of the `<apex:page>` if present, else auto generated id. Then colon and ID of next element in the DOM tree). See if this helps: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_styling_custom_using_component_id.htm
3. Do you have to use IDs? If you have something else unique you could maybe add record's ID as `class`? or ["data"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) element
4. Or there's magical global variable [`{!$Component}`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_component.htm), you could use it to grab the id of right element. Drop the CSS solution and instead have something like `<a onmouseover="show('{!$Component}')" onmouseleave="hide('{!$Component}')">`

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_access.htm
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_best_practices_accessing_id.htm